# Synonym Request: [Sparse-Matrix], [Sparse-Array] [Sparse]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

These all seem to refer to the same thing.
They all have wikis.

- [sparse-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparse-matrix)
- [sparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparse)
- [sparse-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparse-array)

They should be synonyms, but I don't have the tag rep for any of them.

Comment: Just an opinion, I think [tag:sparse] is too broad/ambigue, and the questions need to be retagged to either one and burninate.

Comment: There are 12 [sparse][file] questions (plus 2 [sparse][ntfs]-[file] and maybe more) that should go to [sparse-file].

Comment: [sparse] [file]  and [sparse] [ntfs] are now re-tagged.